# Nokogiri XML Builder error -> "Document already has a root node"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri, builder

In my code I'm building an XML request. However, this simple fragment generates an error:

```
def create_gateways_request
  @request_xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
    xml.gateways(:ua => "#{@plugin_name} #{@version}") {
      xml.merchant {
        xml.account           MSP['merchant']['account_id']
        xml.site_id           MSP['merchant']['site_id']
        xml.site_secure_code  MSP['merchant']['site_code']
      }
      xml.customer {
        xml.country @customer[:country]
      }
    }
  end
  @request_xml.to_xml
end
```

The error:

```
RuntimeError: Document already has a root node
from /Users/scriptdude/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:212:in `add_child'
from /Users/scriptdude/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:549:in `parent='
from /Users/scriptdude/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/builder.rb:371:in `insert'
from /Users/scriptdude/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/builder.rb:363:in `method_missing'
from (irb):146
from /Users/scriptdude/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
from /Users/scriptdude/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/scriptdude/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

The root node is `<gateways>`, right?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have to send the correct XML structure to the Webservice, so I can not take out <gateways>.

Comment: Maybe it's worth adding in a sample XML document of how it is meant to be formatted.

Comment: Agreed with defaye. Going to need an example XML of what to match and also a simple way that we can reproduce it. Please take out all the variables that you're using to build this XML and show us it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this locally, but you might try this at the end of your method instead:

```ruby
@request_xml.doc.to_xml
```

It appears that it thought that you were trying to add a new `<to_xml>` node to the root of the document, and is complaining because you already have a `<gateways>` element at the root. I cannot fathom why Nokogiri 1.5.2 would do this, however, as [Builder does have a `to_xml` method](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html#method-i-to_xml).

Here's my simple test that works for me:

```ruby
require "nokogiri"
def do_it
  @builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new{ |x| x.root{ x.kid } }
  @builder.to_xml
end

puts do_it
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <root>
#=>   <kid/>
#=> </root>

p Nokogiri::VERSION
#=> "1.5.2"
```